# XPath not working out correctly

Tags: java, xpath

I have the following Java code working with XPath to get data from XML elements. The first time the expression is evaulated in `title`, it works as it should. But the next time, in `cost`, whenever I display the value of `cost`, it is just "Could not get cost". Am I missing something when trying to do multiple XPath expressions?

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression exp;
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(woot_xml));
title = "Could not get title";
cost = "Could not get cost";
try {
    exp = xpath.compile("/rss/channel/item/title");
    title = exp.evaluate(inputSource);
    exp = xpath.compile("/rss/channel/item/pubDate");
    cost = exp.evaluate(inputSource);
} catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
    // Do nothing for now
}
```

This is the XML I'm going off of: http://www.woot.com/salerss.aspx

Comment: Well, how does the XML look like?

Comment: tried?: //rss/channel/item/title and //rss/channel/item/pubDate (double // at start)

Comment: I updated my question with the XML. And I tried the // but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does the exception say which you are swallowing? I think that this exception message will enlighten you.

Comment: "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document" is the exception message that I got with `e.printMessage()`

Comment: Exactly. That's because the `InputSource` may only be read once... and it is consumed now.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. What would be a good way to go about doing multiple XPath reads from tat then?

Comment: Load it into a document... have a look at the `DocumentBuilderFactory`, `DocumentBuilder` and `Document` classes for instance. Here's a well-explained sample: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html